# What is wrong with my jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to toggle a div from left to right when someone clicks on the h1 which is floating on right every thing is working just fine but I can't toggle it. Once the div appears it never goes away.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function (){
        /*
        THIS COMMENTED SECTION IS WORKING BUT WITHOUT TOGGLE
        $('h1').click(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
                $('div').animate({
                    'left': 0
                }, 'slow');

            });
        */



// This is not working!
$("h1").click(function(){
    $("div").toggle(function() {
        $("div").animate({'left': '-32%'});
    }, function() {
        $("div").animate({height: '0'});
    });
});



});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<h1>Click here!</h1>
<div style="left: -32%; display: block;">Put whatever content you want here!
<ul>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And even if you are using an older version of jQuery, you're using .toggle() incorrectly.

Comment: Six weeks later, and you are still to reply to your two respondents? Please take the time to reply to people who assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

The first parameter is is not a function.

Comment: So this guy should be check the jquery version and think it .

Comment: There used to be a [different form of `.toggle()` described here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) that took multiple functions as arguments and upon each click on the object, it would rotate calling each successive function on each next click.  Such a feature has been removed from jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

The multiple function argument form of `.toggle()` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 and it had a built in click handler.  So, it didn't work the way you are trying to use it and it is no longer supported.

Here's a replacement for the multi-function version of `.toggle()`:

```
jQuery.fn.cycleFunctions = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // initialize index into function arguments
    var indexTag = "_cycleIndex";
    this.data(indexTag, 0);
    this.on("click", function(e) {
        var self = $(this);
        var index = self.data(indexTag) % args.length;
        self.data(indexTag, index + 1);
        return args[index].call(this, e);
    });
    return this;
};
```

Note, this already does the `.click()` handler for you so you don't put this inside a click handler.

So, combined with your code:

```
<h1>Click here!</h1>
<div class="toggle" style="left: -32%; display: block;">Put whatever content you want here!
<ul>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
    <li>CLICK ON THE LINK</li>
</ul>
</div>

// This works with two operations that are opposites of each other
// which your two animations are not
$("h1").cycleFunctions(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideUp();
}, function() {
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideDown();
});
```

You would then have to fix your CSS to that the two actions are reversible.  In order to move with the left style, the item has to have a non-default position style setting.   And, once the second click happens and the item has a zero height, the item will never be visible again so this could operate two clicks and never be seen again.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xj65L/